# Published Tableau workbook not working inside the html tabs in mozila browser

Tags: javascript, mozilla, tableau-api

I successfully published the `Tableau` worksheet on my website. It is showing the charts on the independent webpage but when I integrate it into my original website tabs it showing the error like
[image]

in Mozilla but it is working in Chrome. Code for that div

```
    <div id="Tableau" class="w3-container city" style="overflow:scroll; height:85%;display:none">
    <div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz151851752543453' style='position: relative'>
<noscript>
<a href='#'><img alt='Pie_Bar ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;al&#47;allbook-final&#47;Pie_Bar&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' />
</a>
</noscript>
<object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'>
<param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' />
 <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value=''/>
<param name='name' value='allbook-final&#47;Pie_Bar' />
<param name='tabs' value='no' />
<param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
<param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;al&#47;allbook-final&#47;Pie_Bar&#47;1.png' />
 <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' />
<param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' />
<param name='filter' value='publish=yes' /></object></div>       
         <script type='text/javascript'>                 
   var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1518517525854');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    vizElement.style.width='1000px';vizElement.style.height='827px';                    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>

        </div>
```

Comment: Are you using any jquery or just straight javascript API?

Comment: I put this inside one of the tabs.

Comment: javascript api which is available in tableau server share link..